# Why is this Haskell code snippet not infinitely recursive?

Tags: haskell, primes, factorization

To help me learn Haskell, I am working through the problems on Project Euler. After solving each problem, I check my solution against the Haskell wiki in an attempt to learn better coding practices. Here is [the solution](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Euler_problems/1_to_10#Problem_3) to [problem 3](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=3):

```
primes = 2 : filter ((==1) . length . primeFactors) [3,5..]

primeFactors n = factor n primes
  where
    factor n (p:ps) 
        | p*p > n        = [n]
        | n `mod` p == 0 = p : factor (n `div` p) (p:ps)
        | otherwise      = factor n ps

problem_3 = last (primeFactors 317584931803)
```

My naive reading of this is that `primes` is defined in terms of `primeFactors`, which is defined in terms of `primes`. So evaluating `primeFactors 9` would follow this process:

1. Evaluate `factor 9 primes`.
2. Ask `primes` for its first element, which is 2.
3. Ask `primes` for its next element.
4. As part of this process, evaluate `primeFactors 3`.
5. Ask `primes` for its first element, which is 2.
6. Ask `primes` for its next element.
7. As part of this process, evaluate `primeFactors 3`.
8. ...

In other words, steps 2-4 would repeat infinitely. Clearly I am mistaken, as the algorithm terminates. What mistake am I making here?

Comment: because, as the answers here say, `primeFactors` only accesses `primes` until the square of a prime exceeds the number being tested, that code is equivalent to `primes = 2:[n | n<-[3..], all ((> 0).rem n) $ takeWhile ((<= n).(^2)) primes]` which is clearly non-looping.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`primeFactors` only ever reads up to the square root of the number it's evaluating. It never looks further in the list, which means it never "catches up" to the number it's testing for inclusion in the list. Because Haskell is lazy, this means that the `primeFactors` test does terminate.

The other thing to remember is that `primes` isn't a function that evaluates to a list each time you access it, but rather a list that's constructed lazily. So once the 15th element has been accessed once, accessing it a second time is "free" (e.g. it doesn't require any further calculation).

Comment: detail: Accessing it a second time still costs 15 dereferencings since we're doing cons cell lists... this can be a lot if you have hundreds of list elements

Comment: @sparkleshy which would be quadratic in (approximately) `sqrt(n)`, i.e. add (approximately) linear cost to an *above-linear* calculation.

Answer (score 8):

Kevin's answer is satisfactory, but allow me to pinpoint the flaw in your logic. It is #6 that is wrong. So we're evaluating `primeFactors 3`:

```
primeFactors 3          ==>
factor 3 primes         ==>
factor 3 (2 : THUNK)    ==>
2*2 > 3 == True         ==>
[3]
```

The THUNK need never be evaluated to determine that the `primeFactor 3` is `[3]`.

Answer (score 7):

`primeFactors 3` doesn't ask `primes` for its next element, only the first one, because `2*2` is greater than `3` already